# Implementing a base entity class when not all entities have an Id property in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, repository

I'm working on implementing the repository pattern in ASP.NET CORE. Basically, I want to implement an IRepository interface like so, it will have more methods but this is the gist of it. It's pretty standard.

```cs
public interface IRepository
{
   T GetById<T>(int id) where T : BaseEntity;
   T Add<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity;
}
```

The `BaseEntity` class

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<BaseDomainEvent> Events = new List<BaseDomainEvent>();
}
```

This is where I hit my problem, I have one many-to-many table designed to represent the parts currently assigned to a discrepancy, `DiscrepancyPart`, that is generated by Entity Core.
**The main problem, though, is it doesn't have an Id property**.

`DiscrepancyPart` and how it's generated

```cs
public class DiscrepancyPart
{
   public int DiscrepancyId { get; set; }
   public int PartId { get; set; }
   public int Qty { get; set; }
   // Discrepancy
   public Discrepancy Discrepancy { get; set; }
   // Part
   public Part Part { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // Many-to-many relationship between Discrepancy and Part
   modelBuilder.Entity<DiscrepancyPart>()
      .HasKey(bc => new { bc.DiscrepancyId, bc.PartId });
   modelBuilder.Entity<DiscrepancyPart>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Discrepancy)
      .WithMany(b => b.DiscrepancyParts)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.DiscrepancyId);
   modelBuilder.Entity<DiscrepancyPart>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Part)
      .WithMany(c => c.DiscrepancyParts)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PartId);
}
```

I hope the problem is fairly straightforward, I don't know how to incorporate this entity using the base entity class, each idea I get just sounds like a massive anti-pattern.

Comment: Perhaps this is a bit over-engineering. I think it's no longer necessary to implement the repository pattern on DbContext. Please read [Is the repository pattern useful with Entity Framework Core?](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/). Another approach is to use extention methods.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I'll be sure to take a look at this and the other links in the article. I think I understand what you mean by extension methods, using LINQ like in the article? That seems like a really good way to approach this situation, I could just make a different extension for the outlying composite key model, that seems a lot more straight-forward.

Comment: In general, there is no need to use IRepository for middle table, you could use `Include` to get the middle table records. Or, what issue do you have if you inherited `DiscrepancyPart` from `BaseEntity`?

Comment: @TaoZhou The problem would be `BaseEntity` would have an Id property. I wouldn't want that in the `DiscrepancyPart` table. If my BaseEntity doesn't have an Id property isn't a huge part of its code reuse thrown out? I know it's not that big of a wrench, but it just seemed silly.

Comment: If you need to use Repository with middle table, your middle table should inherited from `BaseEntity`. I think Id would not cause any issue for `DiscrepancyPart`. If you did not like Id for `DiscrepancyPart`, just do not use `Repository` for `DiscrepancyPart`. Two options, just choose what you like.

Comment: @TaoZhou Okay I see the logic in that. I think I'm going to simply not inherit from the base class in my (now two) join tables. I've decided to go ahead with repositories because although I see the logic in not needing it with EF Core, I want to try out DDD as I think it would help for the complexity of this project.